# How can I do SSH port-forwarding only when the address/port is available?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

I would like to use ssh with port forwarding by default. So I added the following ssh command to a script (with made-up server names):

```
ssh -f -N user@server -L 8080:server:8080
```

where `server` is a remote server. Everything works except that if the script is run a second time, ssh complains that

```
bind [127.0.0.1]:8080: Address already in use
```

Is there a way to tell `ssh` to test and do the port-forwarding only when the port/address is available?

Comment: @Kamil I don't see that your possible dupe answers the question at all.

Comment: Doing nothng would answer the letter of the question: the 2nd ssh will complain, but it's non-fatal. So it would "do the port-forwarding only when the port/address is available". So if the question isn't a dupe, then OP should give more details. Eg: if the 2nd time "server" isn't the same, it would make some sense to ask something. See also: https://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some search, I found from [wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Multiplexing) that the testing can be done by:

1. creating the port-forwarding with a ControlMaster file

`ssh -f -N -M -S /tmp/ssh_pf_%r-%h-%p -L 8080:127.0.0.1:8080 server`

and,

2. testing with the ControlMaster file if the connection is already made:

`ssh -O check -S /tmp/ssh_pf_%r-%h-%p server`

Put together, the following will make the connection only if the it hasn't been made already (I guess, saving a second attempt to connect):

```
if ! ssh -O check -S /tmp/ssh_pf_%r-%h-%p server ;
then ssh -f -N -M -S /tmp/ssh_pf_%r-%h-%p -L 8080:127.0.0.1:8080 server ; fi
```

As pointed out in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/164656), using the ControlMaster file also allows to easily close the connection as follows:

```
ssh -O exit -S /tmp/ssh_pf_%r-%h-%p server
```

There may be better alternatives, but this seems to work so far.